# Python JSON encoding

Tags: python, json, encoding, types, simplejson

I'm trying to encode data to JSON in Python and I been having a quite a bit of trouble. I believe the problem is simply a misunderstanding.

I'm relatively new to Python and never really got familiar with the various Python data types, so that's most likely what's messing me up.

Currently I am declaring a list, looping through and another list, and appending one list within another:

```
import simplejson, json
data = [['apple', 'cat'], ['banana', 'dog'], ['pear', 'fish']]

x = simplejson.loads(data)
# >>> typeError: expected string or buffer..

x = simplejson.dumps(stream)
# >>> [["apple", "cat"], ["banana", "dog"], ["pear", "fish"]]
# - shouldn't JSON encoded strings be like: {{"apple":{"cat"},{"banana":"dog"}}
```

So I either:

- I don't understand JSON Syntax
- I don't understand the Pythons JSON module(s)
- I'm using an inappropriate data type.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Python `lists` translate to JSON `arrays`. What it is giving you is a perfectly valid JSON string that could be used in a Javascript application. To get what you expected, you would need to use a `dict`:

```
>>> json.dumps({'apple': 'cat', 'banana':'dog', 'pear':'fish'})
'{"pear": "fish", "apple": "cat", "banana": "dog"}'
```

Answer (score 29):

I think you are simply exchanging *dumps* and *loads*.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = [['apple', 'cat'], ['banana', 'dog'], ['pear', 'fish']]
```

The first returns as a (JSON encoded) string its data argument:

```
>>> encoded_str = json.dumps( data )
>>> encoded_str
'[["apple", "cat"], ["banana", "dog"], ["pear", "fish"]]'
```

The second does the opposite, returning the data corresponding to its (JSON encoded) string argument:

```
>>> decoded_data = json.loads( encoded_str )
>>> decoded_data
[[u'apple', u'cat'], [u'banana', u'dog'], [u'pear', u'fish']]
>>> decoded_data == data
True
```

Answer (score 18):

In `simplejson` (or the library `json` in Python 2.6 and later), `loads` takes a JSON string and returns a Python data structure, `dumps` takes a Python data structure and returns a JSON string. JSON string can encode Javascript arrays, not just objects, and a Python list corresponds to a JSON string encoding an array. To get a JSON string such as

```
{"apple":"cat", "banana":"dog"}
```

the Python object you pass to `json.dumps` could be:

```
dict(apple="cat", banana="dog")
```

though the JSON string is also valid Python syntax for the same `dict`. I believe the specific string you say you expect is simply invalid JSON syntax, however.

Answer (score 4):

The data you are encoding is a keyless array, so JSON encodes it with [] brackets. See www.json.org for more information about that. The curly braces are used for lists with key/value pairs.

From www.json.org:

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In
>   various languages, this is realized as
>   an object, record, struct, dictionary,
>   hash table, keyed list, or associative
>   array.  An ordered list of values. In
>   most languages, this is realized as an
>   array, vector, list, or sequence.
>
> An object is an unordered set of
>   name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with }
>   (right brace). Each name is followed
>   by : (colon) and the name/value pairs
>   are separated by , (comma).
>
> An array is an ordered collection of
>   values. An array begins with [ (left
>   bracket) and ends with ] (right
>   bracket). Values are separated by ,
>   (comma).

Answer (score 3):

JSON uses square brackets for lists ( `[ "one", "two", "three" ]` ) and curly brackets for key/value dictionaries (also called objects in JavaScript, `{"one":1, "two":"b"}`).

The dump is quite correct, you get a list of three elements, each one is a list of two strings.

if you wanted a dictionary, maybe something like this:

```
x = simplejson.dumps(dict(data))
>>> {"pear": "fish", "apple": "cat", "banana": "dog"}
```

your expected string ('`{{"apple":{"cat"},{"banana":"dog"}}`') isn't valid JSON.  A

Answer (score 3):

So, simplejson.loads takes a json string and returns a data structure, which is why you are getting that type error there.

simplejson.dumps(data) comes back with

```
'[["apple", "cat"], ["banana", "dog"], ["pear", "fish"]]'
```

Which is a json array, which is what you want, since you gave this a python array.

If you want to get an "object" type syntax you would instead do

```
>>> data2 = {'apple':'cat', 'banana':'dog', 'pear':'fish'}
>>> simplejson.dumps(data2)
'{"pear": "fish", "apple": "cat", "banana": "dog"}'
```

which is javascript will come out as an object.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import simplejson
data = {'apple': 'cat', 'banana':'dog', 'pear':'fish'}
data_json = "{'apple': 'cat', 'banana':'dog', 'pear':'fish'}"

simplejson.loads(data_json) # outputs data
simplejson.dumps(data) # outputs data_joon
```

NB: Based on Paolo's answer.