# Python, list dicts to json

Tags: python, simplejson

I have a list of dicts:

```
          for item in list:
          listDicts.append(item.AsDict())
```

How convert listDicts to json string, using simplejson ?
Making the list each dictionary will be an object in JSON.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983855/python-json-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `json.dumps(listDicts)`? It comes out of the box. I'm not sure what simplejson would buy you; in fact, I think they're the same thing.